# how to get absoluteURIbuilder to return newly created resource in loaction header in JAX-RS?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resteasy, uribuilder

Consider the following example:

**create new user**

POST request for this url : www.example.com/accounts/checking/users

**GET user detail**

GET request for this url : www.example.com/accounts/checking/user/1

return resource for user with id 1.

Now my question is
when I post to www.example.com/accounts/checking/users for a new user creation,
a new user is created and its resource uri must be returned in the location header. I am having trouble building this uri using getAbsoluteURIbuilder method.

Here is what I have

```
@Path("/accounts)
public class AccountResourceService {

@Context
UriInfo uriInfo
```

//here 'type' can be checking or saving account

```
@GET
@PATH("{type}/user/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class getUserInfo(final @PathParam("type") String type, @PathParam("id"), int id)
{
    //return user-specific resource for the given id
}


@POST
@PATH("{type}/users")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CreateUser(final @PathParam("type") String type, AccountCreateRequest request)
{
   if type.equals("checking"){
      User user = createAccount(request);
      URI uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder().path(user.getId().toString()).build();
      System.out.println("created uri is " + uri.toString);
      return Response.created(uri).build(); 
    }
    else {
       //do something else
        }

}

}
```

The uri I am returning in POST method above is

```
http://localhost:8080/accounts/checking/users/1 //note users
```

But the expected uri is

```
http://localhost:8080/accounts/checking/user/1 //not user
```

how can I get this to work?

Comment: From a design perspective, I say you just get rid of the `user` resource path, and make it `users/{id}`. This is common and an accepted way. `users` is a collection resource. When you go to `/users`, you get the collection of users. When you go to `users/234`, you get the user with id `234`, in that collection of users.

Comment: @peeskillet: I totally understand but it is legacy code and there is nothing much I can do

Comment: There's not really much you can do but do something ugly that involves removing the `s` yourself then append the id

Comment: constructing from baseURI may be an option, but I am wondering how to do it

Comment: Just use `getAbsolutPath()` (no `Builder`). That should return a `URI`. `toString()` it and remove the `s`. Append the id, then `URI.create(newUriString)`

Comment: Or a _somewhat_ cleaner way is to `UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromUri(removedSUri)`. Then you can `path` the `id`. This way you don't have to worry about the `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put all the comments into an answer

> From a design perspective, I say you just get rid of the user resource path, and make it users/{id}. This is common and an accepted way. users is a collection resource. When you go to /users, you get the collection of users. When you go to users/234, you get the user with id 234, in that collection of users.

But sine you can change this, you can just build the uri with some string manipulation. Get the `getAbsolutePath()` from the `UriInfo`, then just remove the `s`. Then you can create a new `UriBuilder` with that string. As seen in the below example

```
@Path("/accounts")
public class AccountsResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/{type}/users")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createUser(@PathParam("type") String type,
                               @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

        String newUri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString();
        newUri = newUri.substring(0, newUri.length() - 1);
        UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath(newUri);
        URI uri = builder.path("1234").build();

        return Response.created(uri).build();
    }
}
```

This will return `/accounts/checking/user/1234`